# Xamarin Foms UWP - KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary now returns OneDrive

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have been using the below code in one of my apps for months as an app data backup folder and recently the path returned has changed?

```
IStorageItem subFolder = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.TryGetItemAsync("My App Name");
```

Used to return: `C:\Users\Lenovo\Pictures\My App Name`

Now it returns: `C:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive\Pictures\My App Name`

Any ideas on how/why this could have happened?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
string picsFolder = Windows.Storage.UserDataPaths.GetDefault().Pictures;

StorageFolder picsStorageFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(picsFolder);

IStorageItem appFolder = await picsStorageFolder.TryGetItemAsync("My App Name");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the user enabled auto backup in the Onedrive app. When one does it, default directories for Pictures, Documents and so on libraries change their locations. To fix this just change the location of your library. 
To do so just go to `This PC`, right-click desired library (e.g. Pictures), select `Properties` and change location in the `Location` tab.